# MVC3 select int value through LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I am trying to get customerId from Customer table.

However, when I try to make it, it has error said, 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.Iqueryable' to 'int''

How can I get customerId??

Thank you.

Here is my coding.

```
int customerId = from a in db.Customer
                            where a.userName == customerName
                            select a.customerId; 
                           //it has error in here.

order.customerId = customerId;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that your query could return multiple rows. You need to tell LINQ that you only want the first (or a single) result:

```
int customerId = (from a in db.Customer
                  where a.userName == customerName
                  select a.customerId).First();
```

Comment: If `customerID` is unique than it should be `Single()` rather than `First()`

Answer (score 1):

I like using the .Single() function when I know there should be only one row.

```
int customerId = (from a in db.Customer
                  where a.userName == customerName
                  select a.customerId).Single();
```

This throws an exception if more or less than one row is found, which is sometimes useful depending on your situation.

Answer (score 0):

use it this way: 
var customer = db.Customer.FirstOrDefault(c =>c.userName == customerName)
var id = customer.Id

Select returns an IEnumerable, so you can't convert it to int.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more suggestion I can recommend for this question is to use First or default.

```
var customerId = (from a in db.Customer
                            where a.userName == customerName
                            select a.customerId).FirstOrDefault();
```

`order.customerId = customerId;` this should now work fine since it already knows it int